# What is $\gcd(0,a,b)$?

Tags: number-theory

> What is $\gcd(0,a,b)$ when  $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime?

$\gcd(a,b,c)$ is the greatest integer $d$ which divides $a,b$ and $c$ simultaneously. In that case what is $\gcd$ of any triplet containing exactly one zero? If we define $(0,a,b)=\min(a,b)$, then we can easily find a counterexample (As $(0,3,4)$). Can we say that $\gcd(0,a,b)$ is $1$ if $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime?

Comment: $1$ is the largest dividing $a$ and $b$ if they are relatively prime by definition. Does $1$ divide $0$ as well?

Comment: Why did you choose to use $\min$? Wouldn't $\gcd$ be more natural?

Comment: Simply Beautiful Art, yes it does.

Comment: Arthur, you are right. I should have thought a bit more before posting this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$d\mid 0,a,b\iff d\mid a,b\ $ so $\ 0,a,b\,$ and $\,a,b\,$ have the same set $S$ of *common* divisors $\,d,\,$ so they have the same *greatest* common divisor $(= \max S)$

Comment: The same argument works if we replace $0$ by $\,ja+kb\,$ for any $\,j,k\in\Bbb Z\ $ (OP is case $\,j,k=0)\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

An answer more general than the question:

If you use the standard definition of gcd in algebra, namely, $\gcd(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)$ is the nonnegative generator of the ideal $\langle a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\rangle$, it is obvious that $\gcd(0,a,b)$ is the nonnegative generator of the ideal generated  by $a$ and $b$, i.e.
$$\gcd(0,a,b)=\gcd(a,b)=1.$$

Comment: While researching to write an answer, I found a statement that gcd(a[1], a[2], ... a[n-1], a[n]) = gcd(gcd(a[1], a[2], ... a[n-1]), a[n]) if *none* of the *a*s are zero. But I don't see why it shouldn't suffice that *not all* of the *a*s are zero.

Comment: This only works for PIDs, but the result holds much more generally in any GCD domain (or whenever the gcd exists).

Comment: I agree with you. I can't see any side-effect of extending the definition.

Comment: BillBubuque: Yes, but the O.P. asked his question in the context of integers.

Answer (score 0):

The number $0$ is the greatest element in the partial ordering of the set of integers w.r.t. divisibility. Thus the gcd of $0,a,b$ equals the gcd of $a,b$.